# JS - Display a null property from a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that the problem of checking if a value is null or undefined has already been asked, but i'm facing here a problem I don't understand. I made a function to split a string, it works like a charm. But when I pass a null or undefined value, the program stops. What I want is to be able to have a void string instead of the program to stop.
Here is the code :

```
splitString(str: string, length: number) {
    var words = str.split(" ");
    if (typeof(str) === null ){
        return " "
    }
    else {
        for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            var l = words[j].length;
            if (l > length) {
                var result = [], i = 0;
                while (i < l) {
                    result.push(words[j].substr(i, length))
                    i += length;
                }
                words[j] = result.join(" ");
            }
        }
        return words.join(" ");
    }

}
```

And when i call the function with a null value for example, the program stops with the follwing message :

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
```

Any Idea how to be able to avoid the program to stop and make him put a blank string when it's null?
Thank You.

EDIT :
Now working with the following code :

```
splitString(str: string, length: number) {

    if (str != null && str != undefined){
        var words = str.split(" ");
        for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            var l = words[j].length;
            if (l > length) {
                var result = [], i = 0;
                while (i < l) {
                    result.push(words[j].substr(i, length))
                    i += length;
                }
                words[j] = result.join(" ");
            }
        }
        return words.join(" ");
    }
    else if (typeof(str) === null ){
        return " "
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant you test first if the `str` is null, then return and get out of the block early

Comment: you should check for `null` before you try to split the string. And the `typeof null === "object"`. Check for equality, not type

Comment: You have `var words = str.split(" ");` as the first statement in your function, *before* you're checking for `str`'s type.

Comment: True, because by the time he checks for null, the code already complained.

Comment: Thank you all, i succeed thanks to you. That was a big begginer mistake here... I update the code with the correct function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can default to an empty (`" "` in your case) string either in the arguments of the function on inside your code block. Here is an example:

```
splitString(str: string, length: number) {
  var words = (str || " ").split(" ");
  for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    var l = words[j].length;
    if (l > length) {
      var result = [], i = 0;
      while (i < l) {
        result.push(words[j].substr(i, length))
        i += length;
      }
      words[j] = result.join(" ");
    }
  }
  return words.join(" ");  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited the code with the working function.